# EM Field Quantization in Spherical polars

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, coordinate-systems, quantization, spherical-harmonics

Is it possible to quantize the electromagnetic field in spherical polar coordinates instead of cartesian ones? 
Such that creation and annihilation operators correspond to harmonic oscillator modes that are not plane waves but spherical harmonics or something like that.

People I asked told me that "problems arise", however nobody was specific on that issue.

Do you know what are these problems? Or even better do you have a reference where someone carries out the quantization in this way (or at least attempts to do so)?

Comment: There should be a unitary transformation between plane waves and spherical harmonics. It is mentioned at page 45: http://www.quantum.physik.uni-potsdam.de/teaching/ws2011/qo1/script-ch23.pdf